# "The stoppering unit has vacuum" - is there a better way to phrase it?

Tags: phrase-request, translation

I'm translating a filling-and-capping line checklist (pharmaceutical production), and one of the points of the list goes like this:

> Check the vacuum pump for operability. When the pump operates, one can hear the characteristic sound and **witness the presence of vacuum** in the stoppering unit.

Is there a better way to put it?

The Russian original text puts it quite bluntly:

> Проверить работоспособность вакуумного насоса. При включённом насосе слышен характерный звук и **присутствие вакуума в узле укупорки**.
>
> Check the vacuum pump for operability. When the pump operates, one can hear the characteristic sound and **the stoppering unit has vacuum**. (this does not look good in English).

The stoppering of a vial using vacuum looks like this - see this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oh5MEeQoaXk) - only that in my case the system is automated.

Comment: Just an FYI: http://www.pharmtech.com/stoppering-techniques-prefilled-syringes

Comment: "...and **detect** the presence of vacuum" or "..and **detect** the vacuum".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - I wonder if I can cross-post [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17350/how-do-i-call-this-cogwheel-that-feeds-tin-cans-to-a-specific-position) here or on ELU

Comment: Depends on whether you want to translate the text or make it clearer than it is.

Comment: It is not clear what methods are used to "witness" the vacuum. Are there visible signs?  Is a pressure gauge involved?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - what methods? I wish I knew. The text is silent on that.

Comment: **detect** is also not specific as to the means of detection. It is often used in forensic/scientific contexts. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=detect+the+presence%2C+witness+the+presence&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdetect%20the%20presence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwitness%20the%20presence%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I would guess that there is a gauge on the stoppering device that you would use to check the vacuum level. I found this example "System has vacuum and vacuum switches are open." (http://www.steamspecialty.com/cd/engineering_specs/engineering_specs/Shipco/IOM/SHVM_IOM.pdf) so "the unit has vacuum" would be fine I think.

Comment: How about: *"Check that the vacuum pump is operating correctly. When the pump is turned on, you should be able to hear the motor running and verify that the stoppering unit has vacuum."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

> Check that the vacuum pump is operating correctly. When the pump is turned on, you should be able to hear that the motor is running, and (be able to) verify that the stoppering unit has vacuum.